# Dynamic Nested Formsets in Django

Tags: jquery, python, django, django-forms

I've saw a few blog posts (like the one from yergler) about this but haven't been able to find a good elegant solution.

I have 3 Models:

```
class Workflow(models.Model): 
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255) 
    company = models.ForeignKey(Company) 
    class Meta: 
        unique_together = ('name', 'company') 
class Milestone(models.Model): 
    workflow = models.ForeignKey(Workflow) 
    tasks = models.ManyToManyField(Task) 
class Task(models.Model): 
    task = models.CharField(max_length=255)
```

How could I create a form that allows me to add many milestones to a 
workflow and many tasks to a milestone?

Basically, I want to give them a create form or an edit form and allow them to build a workflow with milestones and tasks but would like to allow them to add them dynamically with javascript.

The dynamic/javascript part is easy but I haven't been able to figure out how to nest a formset inside a formset.  i.e the Tasks underneath the Milestone.

Answer (score 0):

Personally I think it's easier to do it without using the formset class at all, and just roll your own NestedFormset class which will, for example, parse data with multiple prefixes - ie

```
1.title => "Milestone 1 title"
2.title => "Milestone 2 title"
1.1.task => "Task for milestone 1"
1.2.task => "Task for milestone 2"
```

I'm pretty sure the person who'll publish such extendable Formset-like class on github will get tons of followers and cudos :P 
I'm not sure whether it is possible to patch the Formset class in a way which would allow nesting while leaving it backwards compatible - judging from my memory of working with it it will be really complicated.